# "npm install" fails giving permission denied error on Aws EC2 t3 linux instance

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-ec2

I am trying to do `npm install` in **AWS EC2 t3 linux instance** and I am getting the below error.

```
npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --depth=1 -q -b master git://github.com/clearbit/needle.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-dcb452b6
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-dcb452b6': Permission denied
```

node version - 10.6.0

npm version - 6.1.0

I can see that the problem is with "clearbit". However I am confused on what is the root cause of this issue. Whether it is a problem with git or npm?

Comment: Its saying permission denied. What user are you using? Does it have required permissions on directories where clone is happening? Under /root ?

Comment: Yeah I am trying from root user only. There is no problem in installing other modules/